# Check if the user is Facebook logged in or not in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have Developed an application that have facebook login functionality for the Login in Application so i implement Two Button in Main Page of app so when click on login with facebook its open facebook login page so my question is when user already login with fb then the button of login should be invisible so i ckeck 
facebook.isSessionValid() is true or false but its getting false everytime

my code

```
        String APP_ID = "**************";
    fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFbLogin);


    if(fb.isSessionValid())
    {
        login.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "" + fb.isSessionValid(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    withoutLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWithoutLogin);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);
    withoutLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View click) {

    if (click == login) {
        loginTofacebook();

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MockTest.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this, withoutLogin.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void loginTofacebook() {
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    if (access_token != null) {
        fb.setAccessToken(access_token);
        Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + fb.isSessionValid());
    }
    if (expires != 0) {
        fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    {
        fb.authorize(this, new String[]{"email", "user_address ", "user_mobile_phone", "publish_stream", "manage_friendlists", "user_checkins", "friends_checkins", "read_friendlists", "manage_friendlists", "friends_birthday"}, new Facebook.DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fbError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                editor.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Preparation.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session == null) {
                // try to restore from cache
                session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(this);
                // Toast.makeText(this, "logout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
session.isOpenSession(); // return true if login
```

Hope this will help